# Check if a child element is present and non empty in XML file

Tags: python, lxml

I have the following xml file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<components version="1.0.0">
    <component type="foo">
        <maintag>
            <subtag>
                <check>Foo</check>
            </subtag>
            <subtag>
                <check></check>
            </subtag>
            <subtag>
            </subtag>
        </maintag>
    </component>
</components>
```

I want to check that each `subtag` element has child element `check` that has non-empty value. It should print an error if:

- `check` is present but is empty
- `check` is not present at all in one or more `subtag`

How would I do that?

I came up with this but it doesn't do exactly what I want

```py
from lxml import etree # type: ignore

def parse_xml(path: str) -> list:

    root = etree.parse(path)
    components = root.xpath("/components/component")

    return list(components)

path = "test.xml"

for p in parse_xml(path)[0].iter('check'):
    if not len(str(p)) > 0:
        print("check tag empty")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can translate your two conditions to an [XPath](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/) :

```
root = etree.parse("test.xml")

expr = "//subtag[not(check/text()) or not(check)]"

not any(e is not None for e in root.xpath(expr)) # False
```

Alternatively, if you need to verbose the checks, you can do something like :

```
for idx, st in enumerate(root.xpath("//subtag"), 1):
    if (check:=st.find("check")) is None:
        print(f"'check' at 'subtag' {idx} is absent")
    elif not check.text:
        print(f"'check' at 'subtag' {idx} is empty")
    else:
        ...
```

Output :

```
# 'check' at 'subtag' 2 is empty
# 'check' at 'subtag' 3 is absent
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically, my idea would be to:

1. Iterate through each `subtag` in `subtags` list.
2. Locate the `check` element.
3. If the `check_elements` list is empty (i.e., the `check` element is not present). print an error message.
4. else, get its text content and check if it's empty or contains only *whitespace*. If it is, print an error message.

A sample would look like:

```py
# ...rest
for component in components:
    subtags = component.xpath(".//maintag/subtag")
    for subtag in subtags:
        check_elements = subtag.xpath("./check")
        if not check_elements:
            print(f"check tag not present at line {subtag.sourceline}") 
            # Added the line number of error as well.
            # You can modify it as per your requirement.
        else:
            check_element = check_elements[0]
            check_text = check_element.text
            if not check_text or check_text.strip() == "":
                print(f"check tag empty at line {check_element.sourceline}")
```

***[SAMPLE CODE](https://replit.com/@msankrit/SuperbLividDemand#main.py)***

Answer (score 0):

Here a solution with `xml.etree.ElementTree` and the `index()`:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml_str = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<components version="1.0.0">
    <component type="foo">
        <maintag>
            <subtag>
                <check>Foo</check>
            </subtag>
            <subtag>
                <check></check>
            </subtag>
            <subtag>
            </subtag>
        </maintag>
    </component>
</components>
"""
root = ET.fromstring(xml_str)

def check(elem):
    if len(elem) == 0:
        print(f"N.O.K Subtag no {root.findall('.//subtag').index(elem)} has no child tag e.g. <check> at all")
    if len(elem) != 0:
        for c in elem.iter():
            if c.tag == "check" and c.text is not None:
                print(f"O.K   Subtag no {root.findall('.//subtag').index(elem)} has <check> tag with text {c.text}")
            if c.tag == "check" and c.text is None:
                print(f"N.O.K Subtag no {root.findall('.//subtag').index(elem)} has empty <check> tag")
    
for sub in root.findall(".//subtag"):
    check(sub)
```

Output:

```
O.K   Subtag no 0 has <check> tag with text Foo
N.O.K Subtag no 1 has empty <check> tag
N.O.K Subtag no 2 has no child tag e.g. <check> at all
```

Or with error code returns:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml_str = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<components version="1.0.0">
    <component type="foo">
        <maintag>
            <subtag>
                <check>Foo</check>
            </subtag>
            <subtag>
                <check></check>
            </subtag>
            <subtag>
            </subtag>
            <subtag>
                <check> </check>
            </subtag>
        </maintag>
    </component>
</components>
"""
root = ET.fromstring(xml_str)

def check(elem):
    # Error Code:
    # 0 -> o.k. <check> exist with text or space
    # 1 -> n.o.k. <check> exist without text
    # 2 -> n.o.k. <check> doesn't exist
    if len(elem) == 0:
        return 2
    if len(elem) != 0:
        for c in elem.iter():
            if c.tag == "check" and c.text is not None:
                return 0
            if c.tag == "check" and c.text is None:
                return 1
    
for sub in root.findall(".//subtag"):
    if check(sub) != 0:
        print(f"Subtag position no {root.findall('.//subtag').index(sub)} has error code {check(sub)}")
```

Output:

```
Subtag position no 1 has error code 1
Subtag position no 2 has error code 2
```